# Javascript: console without browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, shell, unix, console

Is there a script that provides similar functions as Google Chrome javascript console?
I said script? I mean emulator, shell, something with which I can automate my simple actions:

1. Go to page
2. Open javascript console
3. Type there a function
4. Catch output.

In other words, I need any program running custom javascript on web page.
Or any program accessing js browser console.

Comment: you could use tamper monkey https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en. Although this could vary on more specific needs.

Comment: do you need it in a terminal(shell session)?

Comment: Maybe. Any form, the main thing that it will work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) may be what you are looking for.

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

Comment: U'll love http://casperjs.org/